# Find a formula for the Jones polynomial of the disjoint union of two diagrams $K_1$ and $K_2$

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

> Find a formula for the Jones polynomial of the disjoint union of two diagrams $K_1$ and $K_2$.

I am having a lot of trouble with this seemingly easy question. I understand that a Jones polynomial looks like this:

$$V_K(t) = L_K(t^{-1/4}), \text{where}$$ 
$$L_K(A) = (-A^3)^{- \omega (K)} \cdot \langle K \rangle$$

But I don't understand how to apply this to two disjoint diagrams. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**: Online resources have been telling me to using the Skein relation, and so I feel as if the approach I'm taking is not good.

Comment: What definition are you using for the bracket? $\langle K \rangle$?

Comment: My professor defines it as this: $\sum_\sigma \langle K | \sigma \rangle \cdot d^{\Vert \sigma \Vert}$, where $d$ is the degree, and $\langle K | \sigma \rangle$ is a product of A's and B's after doing a bunch of A-splits and B-splits.

Comment: $\sigma$ are the various states of $K$.

Comment: So do the $A$ and $B$ splits care if things are disjoint?

Comment: I suppose knot. Would $\langle K_1 \cup K_2 \rangle = \langle K_1 \rangle + \langle K_2 \rangle$, then?

Comment: I leave this part up to you to convince yourself if that is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle K_1\cup K_2\rangle&=&\sum_{\sigma}\langle K_1\cup K_2|\sigma\rangle d^{\|\sigma\|}\\
&=& \sum_{\sigma_1,\sigma_2}\langle K_1\cup K_2|\sigma_1\cup\sigma_2\rangle d^{\|\sigma_1\cup\sigma_2\|}\\
&=& \sum_{\sigma_1,\sigma_2}\langle K_1|\sigma_1\rangle \langle K_2|\sigma_2\rangle d^{\|\sigma_1\|+\|\sigma_2\|+1}\\
&=&d \langle K_1\rangle\langle  K_2\rangle.
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore
$$V_{K_1\cup K_2}(t)=-(\sqrt{t}+1/\sqrt{t})V_{K_1}(t)V_{ K_2}(t).$$

Answer (score -1):

$V(Sn)(t) = (-t^{-1/2} - t^{1/2})^{n-1}$ where $Sn$ is a n component unlink. This result comes from *An Introduction to Quantum and Vassiliev Knot Invariants* by David M. Jackson Iain Moffatt, P30.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).